# include a JSP file in another with cases

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

How can i include a JSP page in another JSP with the IF structure:

Can i use this part of code in a JSP file:

```
<%
        UtilisateurAction useraction = new UtilisateurAction();
        String statut = useraction.Connect();
        //System.out.println(statut);

        if(statut=="ADMIN"){
      %>    <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>

       <%} 

        else {if(statut=="USER"){%>
            <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>


        <%}} %>
```

Comment: yes, i believe you can

Comment: yes, but generally java code in a jsp page is bad :) what about <c:if>? P.s and maybe you want to use "ADMIN".equals()

Comment: okey but how can use <c:if> ??

Comment: when i try to use <c:if> i have an error "unknown tag", i already add the jstl and standard library !!!!!!! PLZ help

Answer (score 3):

The `<%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>` is static include, so it will include contents of the `menu.jsp` no matter of the condition. But it will be executed only if the condition is true.

The `<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" flush="true"/>` is dynamic include, so, the `menu.jsp` page will actually be called only if the condition is satisfied. But from the other side `menu.jsp` must be a full page, not a page fragment, and cannot use variables defined in the 'parent' page.

So, it really depends on what you want to achieve.

And as Marco suggested, you should use `"ADMIN".equals(statut)` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" flush="true"/>` to include pages in jsp, on conditions checks.

If you are not using jstl and trying to include `menu.jsp` when statut value is either ADMIN or USER, you can do it like:

```
<% if (statut.equals("ADMIN") || statut.equals("USER")) { %>
          <jsp:include page="menu.jsp" flush="true"/>
<% }%>
```

Note that `menu.jsp` should be in the same folder of your current jsp, else give relative path.

Comment: where can i put my conditions ??

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the possibility to use `<c:if>` you must have a *scoped* variable. Attributes of current request, session of application context are with respective scope being request, session and application.

You can easily put variables in page context (valid only for the current jsp, and others included by `@include` but not by `<jsp:include>`) :

```
<%
...
String statut = useraction.Connect();
pageContext.setAttribute("statut", statut);
%>
<c:if test="${statut == 'ADMIN'}">
...
</c:if>
```

But if you want to to many excluvise test the correct tag is `<c:choose>` :

```
<%
String statut = useraction.Connect();
pageContext.setAttribute("statut", statut);
%>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${statut eq 'ADMIN'}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${statut == 'USER'}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <p>Status ${statut} not found</p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I've just tested it it works (on my machine ...), and the otherwise clause could explain why you do not get what you want.

Comment: i tried to add the scoped variable but it doesn't work i have an error that the method addAttributes is not defined for the type pageContext

Comment: @SalimaLifri I'm sorry, I wrote `addAttribute` when I meant `setAttribute` - post edited

Comment: i have no error when i do this, but also it doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: Could you explain what happens then ?

Comment: Nothing it doesn't show the page that i want to include depending on the variable test.

Comment: @SalimaLifri : I've updated my post with a more complete solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i know where the problem. it is in the variable statut it didn't return the value that i want.Now i have to know how to get the statut of the user who is connected.

Answer (score 0):

so i must use the .
what i want is to include different pages depending on the statut value.

```
<%
    UtilisateurAction useraction = new UtilisateurAction();
    String statut = useraction.Connect();
    //System.out.println(statut);

    if(statut=="ADMIN"){
  %>    <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>

   <%} 

    else {if(statut=="USER"){%>
        <%@ include file="menuother.jsp"%>


    <%}} %>
```