# Integrate <c:if> in my JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm tring to integrate  on my JSP file, here is the code that I wrote:

```
<%  UtilisateurAction useraction = new UtilisateurAction();
    String statut = useraction.Connect(); %>

<c:if test=<%"ADMIN".equals(statut);%>>

<%@ include file="../menu/menu.jsp"%>
</c:if> 


<c:if test=<% "SECR".equals(statut);%>>

<%@ include file="../menu/menuother.jsp"%>
</c:if>
```

It doesn't work, I don't know why I have this error in console:

> quote symbol expected     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:222)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1236)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)   at
>   org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.executeResult(RestActionInvocation.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.processResult(RestActionInvocation.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.invoke(RestActionInvocation.java:146)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.execute(DefaultActionProxy.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: possible duplicate of [include a JSP file in another with cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213686/include-a-jsp-file-in-another-with-cases)

Answer (score 0):

Edit : forgot the `test=` in `c:if`

To use `<c:if>` you must have a scoped variable. Attributes of current request, session of application context are with respective scope being request, session and application.

You can easily put variables in page context (valid only for the current jsp, and others included by `@include` but not by `<jsp:include>`) :

```
<%
...
String statut = useraction.Connect();
pageContext.setAttribute("statut", statut);
%>
<c:if test="${statut == 'ADMIN'}">
...
</c:if>
```

Comment: i doubt that "<c:if STATEMENT>" works, you will need to write "<c:if test='STATEMENT'>", mixing conditional statements with XML-tags without proper attribute-assignments is simply bad code.

Comment: @specializt : I forgot to copy the `test=` ... thank for fixing it.